# Google suspended my app due to webview

Tags: google-play, android-webview, suspend

I created a webview app for my website. Google suspended it and after searching I found out that I have to provide them with some sort of permission to display the content of my website. Question is what should that permission be? I am not able to find how to get the website domain ownership. Only thing I can get is the authorization code for the domain. Moreover the website is verified in Google search console with another Google account. As expected I created a new developer account. What should I do so Google knows that the website is mine?

Comment: Hey @Ηλίας, did you find solution to this. I am also going through the same situation. Please help :)

Comment: Hey @AmanDhanda. Yes, I had to provide google support team, with proof that the domain belonged to me. Proof included screenshots from search console, and the hosting provider that I had my domain registered. I had to wait no more than 24 hours to get a reply stating that my app was cleared and that in similar I should provide proof before submitting the app.

Comment: for those who own there website and there app got still suspend please next time notify google team before uploading app https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6320428?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

After so much exploring I understand how we can prevent webview application to be not suspended by Google.

1. your website should be verified by Google Search console.
2. Provide advance notice to the Google Play App Review team. LINK

If you done above 2 step, there is strong possibility that your app will accepted by google play store.

3. If possible you should not just add webview only, try to add first splash screen or use some native android activities. Because Webview is not build for converting website into application. It gives you feature to add website in your android application, so by considering in mind, develop and publish your application.